# Javascript Code to hide and display a panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i want a javascript code to hide/display a panel

The panel has a grid if the grid has data...then the panel should be displayed
and if the grid is empty then the panel should be hidden

I tried this code..but it does not work...

```
<script language="javascript" type = "text/javascript">
    var gridview = (document.getElementById("#<%= gridview1.ClientID %>")) ? true : false;
    if (gridview) {
        document.getElementById("Panel1").style.display = 'inline';
        }
    else {
  document.getElementById("Panel1").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are confusing JQuery notation with standard JavaScript notation. `#` is used in JQuery as an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `#` in `document.getElementById("#<%= gridview1.ClientID %>")`.

Answer (score 0):

in the line -

var gridview = (document.getElementById("#<%= gridview1.ClientID %>")) ? true : false;

instead of using ("#<%= gridview1.ClientID %>") , write the direct id of your grid yourself.like

var gridview = (document.getElementById("gridview1")) ? true : false;

try it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not familiar with C#, so I can't speak for the other part of the code. As for the JavaScript, a couple of things you should know:

1. getElementById does not return a boolean value, it returns an object. So use !! to force convert to boolean
2. getElementById does not tell you whether or not there is a value in the element. It simply returns the DOM object specified by getElementById. You need to check for innerText (for IE, chrome, safari) or textValue (for firefox, chrome, safari) property. If using jQuery, check for .val() or .text() is empty.
3. And getElementById just use the name of the element, without the #. jQuery use that.

Hope it helps,
Angela :)